# What is the natural size metric?

Tags: algorithm

Doing some Algorithms homework and its asking for "a natural size metric for its inputs".

What is a natural size metric? I couldn't find an answer in the book or on Google.

The rest of the question is just asking for the basic operation, which I know is the operation taking the most time, and if the basic operation count can be different for inputs of the same size. I just don't know what a natural size metric is.

Comment: I found this: https://umutzafer.files.wordpress.com/2012/01/solu2.pdf by googling. From here it appears that the word "natural" refers to "meaningful and obvious". You could think of the question alternatively as asking "what is a good metric for measuring the size...".

Comment: It's not a defined term; it's just 3 words stuck together by the usual rules of English.